# Excel Calculations and circular reference

Tags: excel, formula, vba

I need to carry out a maths operation on a column of numbers using the same value from the column and returning the response to the same column.

Example a column has a set of values and i need to divide each of these values by 2. The answer has to be written back into the same column and i cannot add another column.

Bit of a circular loop going on here. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please provide a small example of the input/output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do your specific example by copying the number 2 from somewhere, selecting your column, pasting special, and checking the "divide" radio button.  Shortcut: Alt -> e- > s ->i

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your value is in Range C1. Below will work for one value

```
Range("C1").Value = Range("C1").Value / 2
```

Simply makes the value of C1 equal to half the orginal value of C1